# Are all diseases caused by organisms (microorganisms)?

Tags: pathology

Are there other causes? Or is it correct to say that all diseases are in fact caused by organisms (microorganisms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct to say that all diseases are caused by foreign organisms. Counterexamples are:

- [Cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer) is caused by random [genetic mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation) in the cells of our body. The mutations can be caused by many factors such as ionizing radiation, smoking, chemical toxins etc.
- Diseases such as [stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke) or [heart attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocardial_infarction) are caused by blood clots blocking the blood flow to essential organs.
- [Autoimmune diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoimmune_disease) are caused by the immune system falsely recognizing cells of the body as foreign and attacking that tissue leading to a wide variety of symptoms.
- [Alzheimer's disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alzheimer%27s_disease) is caused by chronic neurodegeneration, meaning that the cells in the brain die. The causes are not quite understood but as Alzheimer's usually appears late in life it is likely related to ageing. Also, it is known that some genetic defects can lead to early-onset Alzheimers.
- Prion proteins can cause diseases such as [Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creutzfeldt%E2%80%93Jakob_disease) also known as mad-cow disease.
- Hereditary diseases such as early-onset Alzheimers or [ALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis) are cause by gene defects inherited from the parents.
- Toxins can cause chronic diseases such as [lead poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_poisoning).

The list probably goes on...

Please note that the first two on the list are the most common cause of death in developed countries.